# Shared Secret based on Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman with CommonCrypto

Tags: ios, cryptography, diffie-hellman, shared-secret

I am looking for the methods in CommonCrypto to generate the shared secret based on ECDH (Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman). I can find proprietary implementations like this one https://github.com/surespot/surespot-ios/blob/master/surespot/encryption/EncryptionController.mm but this one is not using CommonCrypto. The method to calculate the shared secret is called sometimes Key Exchange and includes the calculation of the shared secret. Can someone send a link to the right documentation or to an example that uses CommonCrypto for generating the shared secret based on Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman?

Answer (score 1):

Look at CommonCrypto function from CommonECCryptor.h

> **CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret**( CCECCryptorRef privateKey, 
>                                   CCECCryptorRef publicKey, 
>                                   void *out, 
>                                   size_t *outLen)

It constructs a Diffie-Hellman shared secret with a private and public ECC key.
Most information they provide are in the header file's commence lines.
[Header of CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret is here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60061/include/CommonECCryptor.h)

Comment: That is nice but do you have an include path? `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonECCryptor.h>` does not work. Is this in the Security Framework? Is it a public API?

Comment: #import ? My answer's URL links to C/C++ header. C includes headers with #include.

Comment: I'm not so modern as you:) I use old C. The test that in particular invokes this  function is [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60026/CCRegression/CommonCrypto/CommonEC.c)

Comment: The issue is iOS that can only use public APIs.

Comment: The author of question was looking for the methods in CommonCrypto to generate the shared secret based on ECDH. I pointed to the function. The question does not contain any restrictions (App store, language, etc.). Author should decide if his environment allows such method.

Comment: The question is tagged "ios", that would be considered a restriction.

Comment: Zaph, I have no iOS now to test, author didn't share his results. So if you have no updates I will delete my answer. Please let me know.

Comment: I think you should look to `SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult` for a modern and secure approach and also Apple reccomendation

Comment: Is there an example code of how to use CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret in swift ? with private and public EC keys ?