# Use ecc for encryption in ios

Tags: python, ios, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve, commoncrypto

I am trying to implement ecc technique for encryption.
I went through the following posts:

1. [Shared Secret based on Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman with CommonCrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750532/shared-secret-based-on-elliptic-curve-diffie-hellman-with-commoncrypto)
2. [Elliptic Curve Crypto in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916695/elliptic-curve-crypto-in-ios/16477728#16477728)

which doesn't have any satisfactory solutions.

Now, I am thinking of using a python library
 https://github.com/yann2192/pyelliptic

But I am not aware if this would be the better solution for using  ecc for encryption as I would still need to figure out a way to use the python library in objc.

Can somebody point me in right direction?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3691738/4029893

Comment: @bad_keypoints I couldn't find any suitable link for using python library in objc

Comment: What are you trying to use ECC for? Signing? Key exchange? In general I'd recommend NaCl (http://nacl.cr.yp.to/), which I believe has a C implementation, and most of the public key stuff uses elliptic curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made my own library for ECC/ECDSA which is now available on [github](https://github.com/SandeepAggarwal/CryptoppECC)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @puzzlepalace's comment, you might wanna try [Libsodium](http://doc.libsodium.org/bindings_for_other_languages/index.html). They even have a Swift library.